# Disable shrinking webview if keyboard or dropdown menu shows up IOS

Tags: ios, webview, keyboard, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

If the keyboard or a dropdown menu shows up, the webview shrinks and moves upward. I'm searching for a phonegap plugin (config.xml)  which effects that the keyboard just overlays the webview instead of shrinking it?
I can't find anything helpful...

Using phonegap build | IOS 9

Maybe somebody got an idea?

Comment: You should probably show the code that creates your layout

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Keyboard Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard#keyboardshrinkview) from Apache. It hasn't been updated in a while but should do what you're asking.

Install

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard
```

Example

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
}
```